# How to compare the elements of an array of characters to the letters of a String

Tags: java, arrays, string

I'm completely new to Java, And I have been working on a test project that requires me to compare the elements of a Char array to the letters of a String, And I don't know how to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Turn the array of characters into a string, or turn a string into arrays of characters:

```
char[] chars = {'a', 'b', 'c'};
String asString = new String(chars);
char[] back = asString.toCharArray();
```

To check if 2 char arrays are equal:

```
java.util.Arrays.equals(charArray1, charArray2)
```

To check if 2 strings are equal:

```
string1.equals(string2);
```

Note that this does not work:

```
charArray1 == charArray2 // does not work. This checks if they are references to the same array, NOT if the contents are equal

string1 == string2 // also does not work; same reason.
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `String.valueOf` to convert a character array to a String:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        char[] chars = {'f', 'o', 'x'};
        String s1 = "fox";
        String s2 = "not fox";

        System.out.println(s1.equals(String.valueOf(chars)));
        System.out.println(s2.equals(String.valueOf(chars)));
    }

}
```